# Magento 2 brokes after compile command

Tags: magento2, error

I'm using magento 2 , and everytime when I do compile command , and I reload my website , it misses some files , getting several errors like this one 
`http://mywebsite/pub/static/frontend/Venustheme/yume/en_GB/js/countdown-home/jquery-migrate.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

and the page is all a mess because of that..

I try to do deploy.. but the page doesn't change.. any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove some folders and set permissions for some directories. 
Go to your Magento root directory and run the following commands :

1. rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/view_preprocessed/* var/composer_home/cache/*
2. sudo chmod 777 var -R
3. sudo chmod 777 pub -R
4. sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
5. Repeat step 2 & 3 once above deployment completed.